# How to refactor properly in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring

I'm working with JavaFX and whenever I move a class to another package I have to update all my FXML files to point to the correct location of classes.

In Eclipse you get an option to apply refactoring changes to the XML files and even non-code text files. However Netbeans only makes changes in Java code and nothing else.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I'd say that this is a better question to as the developers of netbeans, but yes, I think this is limitation of the refractory

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"this is a better question to as the developers of netbeans"* Yeah. But maybe someone has found some sort of work around like a plugin or some steps one could take to ease the pain. It's really annoying when you have to update 50 XML files just to rename a class.

Comment: Maybe they have, but that's not what you're asking, is it? You're asking *why* it doesn't already do it 'properly', and that is a question for the developers. Anything you get here about that is just opinion and guesswork.

Comment: @EJP Fixed. Since there aren't any answers I changed the direction of the question.